# How to correctly declare "extern"?

Tags: arrays

If ‘char a[10];’ is defined in one file and ‘extern char *a;’ is declared in another file then it does not work. Is it correct? 
The declaration ‘extern char *a;’ does not declare an array and therefore
does not match the actual definition.

Comment: It would depend on the language, which you neglected to identify.

Comment: What evidence do you have that this "does not work"?

Comment: Please could you [edit] your question to include more details, such as: the language you are using; a [mcve] of what you have now; the exact result or error message you're getting; and the result you were hoping for or expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Correct -- all declarations of a global symbol must be compatible with the definition of that symbol, or you get the dreaded Undefined Behavior.  `extern char *a;` is not compatible with `char a[10];`.

You could use either `extern char a[10];` or `extern char a[];`, both of which are compatible with `char a[10];` instead.